# VIM: How to count a pattern on a line restricting from column A to column B similar to :s/,//gn?

Tags: vim

I have a line that looks like the following, which I am viewing in vim.

```
 0,0,0,1.791759,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5.278115,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
```

It is from a feature vector file, each row is an instance and each column is the feature value for that feature number.  I would like to figure out which feature number 5.27 corresponds to.  I know the

```
s/,//gn
```

will count the number of commas in the line, but how do I restrict the command to count the number of commas in the line up to the columns with the number 5.27?

I have seen these two posts that seem relevant but cannot seem to piece them together:   [How to compute the number of times word appeared in a file or in some range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398989/vim-how-to-compute-the-number-of-times-word-appeared-in-a-file-or-in-some-range)   and    [Search and replace in a range of line and column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847018/search-and-replace-in-a-range-of-line-and-column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s/,\ze.*5\.27//gn
```

The interesting part is the `\ze` which sets the end of the match. See `:h /\ze` for more information

Comment: I was not aware of the \ze atom, which sets the end of the match to whatever is specified - in this case 5.27.  Have to add that to the bag of search wizardry.

Answer (score 1):

Select the wanted area with visual mode and do

```
:s/\v%V%(,)//gn
```

`\v` enables us to escape less operators with `\`

`%V` limits the search to matches that start inside the visual selection

`%()` keeps the search together if you include alternations with `|`

It's not pretty but it works. See help files for `/\v`, `\%V` and `\%(`

There are also several versions of a plugin called vis.vim, which offers easier commands that aim to do just the above. However I haven't gotten any of them to work so I'll not comment on that further.

Comment: I contemplated restricting the question to non visual mode as on the machine I was using I didn't have visual.  However, I thought that others could benefit (as would I) to see a visual solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
s/,.\{-}5.27//gn
```

it should work.

Comment: This will not work as `\{-}` will prefer a match that starts earlier to a shorter match. See `:h non-greedy`

Comment: @PeterRincker it should. i need non-greedy here. it searches the string in the form of `comma-whatever string follows-5.27`. without non-greedy, `.*` will eat `5.27` too.

Comment: It does consume the comma all the way though the end of `5.27` meaning that is what you are counting. This will yield only 1 match on the given text. You need either to use a positive look-ahead or end the match via `\ze`.

Comment: It looks to not work here in this case as is, but perhaps as @PeterRincker says the \ze will fix it.